How to "dir" a folder on my phone?
Environment: Computer: Windows 11 / Phone: Android 9 (Yeah, It's old.)
If I want to save the contents of a folder on my computer, I can go to Command Prompt and do:
dir "folder_path" > file_to_save_in.txt

where "folder_path" is the folder specification shown in Windows Explorer.
If I do a USB connection to my phone, I can see it's folders in Windows Explorer. For example, the specification of the folder with photos taken on the phone is:
This PC\moto g(6) (XT1925DL)\Internal shared storage\DCIM\Camera

But if I enter this in Command Prompt:
dir "This PC\moto g(6) (XT1925DL)\Internal shared storage\DCIM\Camera" > "dir of photos on phone.txt"

I get the message:
The system cannot find the path specified.

How can I get a folder listing of the files in a folder on my phone?

Use auto complete by pressing tab within Windows Terminal.
